# Writing into a file with a variable taken from a list in txt file

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create an xml file in Python using a txt list. In that list I have different objects which I need to use to name the created file and also add those objects into the xml code that i am inserting.

My code looks like this :

```
List = open(r"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\CTT\Feeder.txt")
List2 = ('D707_FEEDER_' + s.strip() for s in List)
for item in List2: 
open(r"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\CTT\Templates\%s.xml"%(item,), 'w')List.close()
```

My list of objects "s" is called `Feeder.txt`, I managed to create a code that loops through the Feeder.txt file and creates a file for each object with a filename based on the list of objects in Feeder.txt. Now I would like to insert an xml code into all the files in the list that i just created and use the same variable ('s') to write into each of the file.

So now an example of a file with my file name is `D707_FEEDER_R407` and I would like to insert a code into that files :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<envGroups/>
<item>xxx<item/>
```

and replace the 'xxx' with my 's' variable which in this case is R407 so i would like my code to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<envGroups/>
<item>R407<item/>
```

I did try this :

List = open(r"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\CTT\GlobalFilter.txt")
List2 = ('D607_GBF_' + s.strip() for s in List)
    for item in List2:
    f = open("Templates\%s.xml"%(item,), 'w')
    f.write("\n")
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(f"{s.strip() for s in List}")
List.close()
f.close()

but when I open the created xml document instead of the value "R407" I am getting this: `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0988C878>`.
Can I please ask for an advise on how to fix this? 
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Try making the statement in your write() function into an f-string so that the stripped values of s in list are placed in the string within the {curly brackets}

```
write(f"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n
<envGroups/>\n
<item>{s.strip() for s in List}<item/>\n
")
```

Also, if you could provide the syntax error message, that might help the investigation further.

Comment: Hi Shavi, I tried this and instead of my value I am getting this in my xml code: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0988C878>.

Comment: I'm not sure of the content of your file but it would seem that you may need to navigate within that object to find the value you're looking for... 

Try:

`import inspect as inspect`  
`inspect.getmembers(yourObject);`

where 'yourObject' the variable 's' or wherever you're getting that <generator object>.

Comment: ^^^ This should show you all of the methods and variables available within the object.